# How do I convert QMap<QString, QMap<QString, int> > to a QVariant?

Tags: c++, qt4, nested, qvariant, qmap

`QVariant` (needed for `QSettings` class) supports creation from `QMap<QString, QVariant>`

But trying to initialise something like this:

```
QMap<QString, QVariant(QMap<QString, QVariant>)> i;
```

Gives the error:

> function returning a function.

So then I tried the `QMap<QString, QVariant>` overload for `QVariant()` and got

> error: no matching function for call to `QVariant::QVariant(QMap<QString, QMap<QString, int> >&)`

Now I tried a typecast:

```
QMap<QString, (QVariant)QMap<QString, QVariant> > i;
```

and got

> template argument 2 is invalid
>   invalid type in declaration before '`;`' token

So what's the required voodoo to convert a nested `QMap` to a `QVariant` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error being reported is that `QVariant(...)` is not a type, but a function (c-tor).

You should have just used: `Map<QString, QVariant> i;` and used `QVariant(QMap<QString, QVariant>)` only when assigning values to the map.  The point is `QVariant` is *anything* really.  So a map of `QVariants`, can have an `int` in one position (contained in the `QVariant`) and a `QDate` in another.  So when declaring the type, you can't specify which types you want `QVariant` to hold.

Comment: Thanks, i think i had my thought processes going the wrong way, (When all you have is a hammer...), i've settled on using QList<QVariantMap>

Answer (score 6):

1. In `QMap<QString, QVariant(QMap<QString, QVariant>)>`, you have defined a map from a string to a function type. What you really want is a `QMap<QString, QVariant>`.
2. You don't want a `QMap<QString,(QVariant)QMap<QString, QVariant> >` because that's just syntactically incorrect. Both template parameters need to be type names, and typecast can't be part of at type name.
3. Putting a `QMap<QString, int>` (or almost any other type of `QMap`) into a `QVariant` won't work. The only `QMap` type that can be converted into a `QVariant` is a `QMap<QString,QVariant>`.

   There's a typedef for this type that may be useful: `QVariantMap`. If you stick to using `QVariantMap` for this situation, then things will work properly for you.

Comment: Looking over some intricate C++ details, my point #1 isn't totally correct: I thought that `QVariant(QMap<QString, QVariant>)` it's a function type because `std::function` (from C++0x) accepts it as a function type, but it's actually something more complicated -- std::function makes it look like a function type, while it actually uses partial specialization and varadic templates to make it work.